# React SSR and Hydration - Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <div>

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, hydration

I am running into the issue `Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <div>`... when trying to hydrate my application on the client

I have tried removing most of the app and still run into the same error, so not sure what else could be wrong...

This is my SSR code:

```
import App from './app';

const router = express.Router();
router.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  res.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        // tags for google ads etc
      </head>
      <body>
        <div data-ui-role="content" id="root">
  `);
  
  const stream = renderToNodeStream(<App />);
  stream.pipe(res, { end: false });
  stream.on('end', () => {
    res.locals.context = JSON.stringify(store.getState());
    res.end(
      `</div><script src="/assets/vendor.bundle.js"></script><script src="/assets/main.bundle.js"></script></body></html>`
    );
  });
});
```

And then I have my client hydration

```
import App from './app';

export const render = Component => {
  const hydration = hydrateRoot(
    document.getElementById('root');
    <Component />
  );

  return hydration;
}

render(App);
```

And App.js is a simple react component

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but not sure what.

I've checked what the server responds, and what the client responds, and it looks exactly the same... and if I remove the vendor bundle it doesn't throw the error. But unsure how I figure out what package is causing the issue

Note: I am in the middle updating to use `renderToPipeableStream`, but that shouldn't affect the hydration